# How can I use ping with a large packet size to troubleshoot network issues?

Tags: router, ping, networking

What types of network problems can be identified with ping of a large packet size?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Such pings are useful for:

- Discovering how sizes affect latencies
- Discovering packet reassembly issues
- With no-fragment set, discovering faults in MTU detection
- On wireless networks:

  - Discover the effect of packet size on fragmentation settings
  - Providing a consistent source of traffic to do RF analysis

Comment: And don't forget "finding nodes with IP stacks old enough to be vulnerable to the ping of death"!